Bone Layer Won't Change
For context I am Using Blender 4.1.1.0 Somehow I've managed to get all of my bones unassigned from any layer, I'm trying to put them on a layer so I have access to them, I'm Selecting them in the Outliner (As I have no other way to Select the bones).
In Pose mode

Change Bone Layer ( I can see there is no layer selected)
Select the Layer I want the bone to assign to
The Layer does not change.

I follow the same steps and I can see that it still has no layer selected, I'm really not sure what else I can do


I believe it was a glitch, I copied and pasted the project into a fresh blender save and it was all fixed
